# How to proportionally (respecting aspect ratio) scale a rectangle?

Tags: python, math, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to simply take a given box of `x` by `y` and scale it up, either by setting `x` and finding `y`, or vice versa. How would this formula be expressed in Python (for readability's sake). I'm trying to fit this box inside of a larger box so that the inner box always fits within the larger box.

Comment: Is the new rect supposed to be centered inside the larger box? (i.e. letterboxed?)

Comment: I can do the math to center the new rect, that's not too hard. I always get confused by the actual resizing math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NB: I don't really do Python, so this is pseudocode.

What you need is the relative aspect ratios of the two boxes, since that determines which of the new axes must be the same size as the new box:

```
r_old = old_w / old_h
r_new = new_w / new_h

if (r_old > r_new) then
   w = new_w              // width of mapped rect
   h = w / r_old          // height of mapped rect
   x = 0                  // x-coord of mapped rect
   y = (new_h - h) / 2    // y-coord of centered mapped rect
else
   h = new_h
   w = h * r_old
   y = 0
   x = (new_w - w) / 2
endif
```

Answer (score 6):

`new_y = (float(new_x) / x) * y`

or

`new_x = (float(new_y) / y) * x`

Comment: just what i needed without the fluff

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import fractions
>>> x, y = 10, 10
>>> fix_rat = fractions.Fraction(x, y)
>>> fix_rat
Fraction(1, 1)
>>> x = 8
>>> if fractions.Fraction(x, y) != fix_rat:
    y = x / fix_rat #well instead of y you should put the last one that has been changed
                    #but this is just an example


>>> y
Fraction(8, 1)
>>>
```